# Nativescript - ReferenceError: FIRAuth

Tags: ios, iphone, typescript, firebase, nativescript

I am currently developing an application using Nativescript.

Everything works fine with Firebase on the local emulator, but when I test the application on my iPhone I get the following errors

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:2172:24: Error in firebase.login: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FIRAuth
```

I though it might be something to do with where I was initialising Firebase, so I moved `firebase.init()` from `app.models.ts` into the first view as read in other forum posts.

I am really confused as to why this is working perfectly on the emulator but not on my device.

If anybody could shed some light that would be amazing.

```
Stack:
    iPhone SE,
    Nativescript (Angular)
    Firebase
    nativescript-plugin-firebase
```

If you need anymore information please don't hesitate to ask.

#### GoogleService-info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>API_KEY</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
    <string>org.nativescript.xxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>STORAGE_BUCKET</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxx.appspot.com</string>
    <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
    <string>1:xxxxxxxxx:ios:xxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>DATABASE_URL</key>
    <string>https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

#### firebase.nativescript.json

```
{
    "external_push_client_only": false,
    "using_ios": true,
    "using_android": true,
    "firestore": true,
    "realtimedb": true,
    "authentication": true,
    "remote_config": false,
    "performance_monitoring": false,
    "messaging": false,
    "in_app_messaging": false,
    "crashlytics": false,
    "storage": true,
    "functions": false,
    "facebook_auth": false,
    "google_auth": false,
    "admob": false,
    "dynamic_links": false,
    "ml_kit": false
}
```

Comment: What is the version of NativeScript which you are currently using and the plugin used to connect to Firebase?

Comment: NativeScript ver.6.0.3

Comment: Did you enable `authentication` in `firebase.nativescript.json`? Did you try a clean build?

Comment: I have updated the question with the `googleService-info.plist` and `firebase.nativescript.json`

Comment: Also as mentioned, this works perfectly in the emulator, it's only when I test on a real device I see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you cannot preview on a physical device if you use `nativescript-plugin-firebase`.

You get the following error:-

```
Plugin nativescript-plugin-firebase is not included in preview app on device 3CDExxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-960121C3xxxx and will not work.
```

The application will run, but you will not be able to use any of the Firebase modules.

I hope this helps someone having the same issue.

If anybody knows a work around, without having to purchase a licence from Apple for testing, please let me know in the comments.